# sql express table don't have "Create table" option in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-express

I just opened new Sql express database in visual studio 2013.
now, when I go to this database in Server Explorer and trying to create a table in Tables, I don't have any create option. I have only 2 options: Refresh and Properties.
everything is define well, if I go to Modify connection and press Test Connection

I'm using SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2014.

Waste too much time on it

Comment: someone can give me a hook ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it :-)

i was missing "Sql server tools" in Visual studio 2013.

you can search it and download :
VS 2013 -> TOOLS -> EXTENSIONS AND UPDATES